# Google Sign-In Button sends Post requests to play.google.com with 401 code response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-signin

I have a Google Sign In Button in my App. And it works fine. But if user is not authorized (default state), I have an error message in console.

[image]

My app doesn't use any play.google.com services. Why it's trying to connect to it? And how to disable this?

Code, that render button:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client";
    script.id = "google-client-script";
    const buttonRef = googleButtonRef.current!;
    script.onload = () => {
      if (
        window !== undefined &&
        window.google !== undefined &&
        buttonRef !== null
      ) {
        window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
          client_id: clientId,
          callback: handleCredentialResponse, // get auth response
        });
        window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(
          buttonRef,
          { type: "icon", shape: "circle" } // customization attributes
        );
      }
    };
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);}, 
[]);
```